# Regular expression for start and end of string in multiline mode

Tags: regex, perl, pcre

In a regular expression, in multiline mode, `^` and `$` stand for the start and end of line. How can I match the end of the whole string?

In the string

```
Hello\nMary\nSmith\nHello\nJim\nDow
```

the expression

```
/^Hello(?:$).+?(?:$).+?$/ms
```

matches `Hello\nMary\Smith`.

I wonder whether there is a metacharacter (like `\ENDSTRING`) that matches the end of the whole string, not just line, such that

```
/^Hello(?:$).+?(?:$).+?\ENDSTRING/ms
```

would match `Hello\nJim\nDow`. Similarly, a metacharacter to match the start of the whole string, not a line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are indeed [assertions (perlre)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Assertions) for that

> `\A`     Match only at beginning of string
> `\Z`     Match only at end of string, or before newline at the end
>
> ...
> The `\A` and `\Z` are just like `^` and `$`, except that they won't match multiple times when the `/m` modifier is used, while `^` and `$` will match at every internal line boundary.  To match the actual end of the string and not ignore an optional trailing newline, use `\z`.

Also see [Assertions in perlbackslash](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Assertions).

I am not sure what you're after in the shown example so here is another one

```
perl -wE'$_ = qq(one\ntwo\nthree); say for /(\w+\n\w+)\Z/m'
```

prints

```
two
three
```

while with `$` instead of `\Z` it prints

```
one
two
```

---

Note that the above example would match `qq(one\ntwo\three\n)` as well (with a trailing newline), what may or may not be suitable.  Please compare `\Z` and `\z` from the above quote for your actual needs. Thanks to [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) for a comment.

Comment: Do \A and \Z work in JavaScript?  They don't seem to.

Comment: @OsamaBinLogin No, it indeed doesn't seem that JS has that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

`\A` and `\z` always match the beginning and the end of the string, respectively.

```
       without /m              with /m

\A     Beginning of string     Beginning of string
^      \A                      \A|(?<=\n)

\z     End of string           End of string
\Z     \z|(?=\n\z)             \z|(?=\n\z)
$      \z|(?=\n\z)             \z|(?=\n)
```

Put differently,

```
┌─────────────────── `\A` and `^`
│     ┌───────────── `(?m:$)`
│     │ ┌─────────── `(?m:^)`
│     │ │     ┌───── `\Z` and `$`
│     │ │     │ ┌─── `\z`, `\Z` and `$`
│     │ │     │ │
F o o ␊ B a r ␊
```

Remember, all of these matches are zero-length.